# Django / Python - return a sorted list from generated values each assigned to an object

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Django template_tag as follows:

The goal: Based on user input from a search query return houses within a specified radius of the user. (e.g. Show me homes within 15 miles of [MY_LOCATION].)

```
@register.assignment_tag
def nearest_homes(location, distance_from):

    # Retrieve the locations coords, amongst other things
    current_location = geocode(location)

    # Now we have lat and long
    current_location_coordinates = [current_location[1], current_location[2]]

    results = []

    for home in homes:
        home_coords = [home.latitude, home.longtitude]

        # Output is float in miles (e.g. 15.548964313)
        distance = distance_miles(current_location_coordinates, home_coords)
        if distance <= distance_from:
            results.append(home)

    return results
```

This solution works just fine and does its job - however the list "order" is completely random. I would like it to be in ascending order in terms of miles away (which is what the **distance** variable returns above in the for loop.)

Since I am returning a list of objects how can I append / assign a new variable (in this case distance to each object) and return that as a sorted list? Seems like a lot of trouble to just return a simple number.

Here is the html template code for whatever reason:

```
{% nearest_homes user_location distance as homes %}
{% if homes %}
    {% for home in homes %}
        <p>{{ home.address }}</p>
    {% end for %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First append to your `restults` list the distance and the home as a tuple. Then, you can use the `sort` method on the `results` list passing a function to the `key` keyword argument of the `sort` method. For example, `results.sort(key=lambda item:item[0])` would make the sort method compare the first element of the each of the items it's sorting. See: [Python list sorting howto](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions)

This is how I'd do it:

```
results = []

for home in homes:
    home_coords = [home.latitude, home.longtitude]

    distance = distance_miles(current_location_coordinates, home_coords)
    if distance <= distance_from:
        results.append((distance,home))

results.sort(key=lambda item:item[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could probably do is, construct a list of dictionaries  and then sort the dictionaries. Some like

```
 result_home = {home:distance} 
 results.append(results_home)
```

and then use OrderedDict to sort the dictionary.

Note:

OrderedDict in python 2.7.6